# How can I install openssl for PHP 5.4 in my wamp server?

Tags: php, openssl

I have tried by removing the comment for openssl. But my application is showing that:

**The PHP OpenSSL extension doesn't seem to be installed. You need to install PHP with the OpenSSL extension.**

Comment: Did you restart the server after making that change?

Comment: Yes I have restarted. I haven't installed any files. Just removed the comment ; in ini file.